# Understanding density operator of the bath state for quantisation volume larger than de-broglie wavelength

Tags: statistical-mechanics, density-operator, quantum-statistics

I have been reading the paper ["Collisional decoherence reexamined"](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303094) by K. Hornberger and J.E. Sipe.

In the sub-section II-B titled "Convex decompositions of the bath density operator" on page 6 the authors say:

> In thermal equilibrium, at temperature $k_BT = \beta^{-1}$, the bath
> state is specified by the density operator: $$\rho^{bath} = \frac{\lambda^3}{\Omega}e^{-\beta\mathfrak{p}/(2m)}$$
> provided $\Omega$ is much larger than the cube of the thermal de broglie wavelength

Here $\Omega$ is the normalization volume and $\mathfrak{p}$ the momentum operator for a bath particle.

Firstly, how did the bath density operator have this specific form?

It looks to me like a canonical ensemble density matrix $\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta H}$ but I can't make sense of the pre-factor in place of the partition function.

Secondly, why would canonical ensemble be used instead of the grand canonical ensemble ?

I almost always get confused about when is Grand Canonical Ensemble (GCE) is used and when is Canonical Ensemble used?

A heat bath allows exchange of both energy and particles so shouldn't GCE be always used?